# Variable is bigger than byte size, why?

Tags: c#

I've a code dealing with `FromBase64String` as follows:

```
string hashValue = "4Nhuu2LRLntxkUs8Nb0DzL84GRgi5AWhsf+fhfiy6BwTNiM9UUZSdFfWhkCond9hkBBZOA==";
// trying to convert the above string in to bytes.
byte[] toBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(hashValue);
```

Now, in the Locals window `toBytes` has the following values shown.

```
toBytes {byte[52]}  byte[]
[0] 224 byte
[1] 216 byte
[2] 110 byte
[3] 187 byte
[4] 98  byte
[5] 209 byte
[6] 46  byte
[7] 123 byte
[8] 113 byte
[9] 145 byte
[10]    75  byte
[11]    60  byte
[12]    53  byte
[13]    189 byte
[14]    3   byte
[15]    204 byte
[16]    191 byte
[17]    56  byte
[18]    25  byte
[19]    24  byte
[20]    34  byte
[21]    228 byte
[22]    5   byte
[23]    161 byte
[24]    177 byte
[25]    255 byte
[26]    159 byte
[27]    133 byte
[28]    248 byte
[29]    178 byte
[30]    232 byte
[31]    28  byte
[32]    19  byte
[33]    54  byte
[34]    35  byte
[35]    61  byte
[36]    81  byte
[37]    70  byte
[38]    82  byte
[39]    116 byte
[40]    87  byte
[41]    214 byte
[42]    134 byte
[43]    64  byte
[44]    168 byte
[45]    157 byte
[46]    223 byte
[47]    97  byte
[48]    144 byte
[49]    16  byte
[50]    89  byte
[51]    56  byte
```

My Question is `hashValue` is about 72 long string and when converted to `toBytes`, why is it showing of size 52? I've gone through many sources dealing with this but still unable to fix this. Any help in this is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

They are both different things.

When you convert a byte array to its base64 representation, what you're actually doing is text-encoding a binary value, in this case a byte[].

What you're comparing in the question is length of the string of the base64 representation to the length of your source byte array, which is totally different from the encoded value.

Answer (score 2):

Because in Base64, each 4 encoded characters represents 3 bytes (technically, 3 octets).